# audio and video streaming - managing CPU and bandwidth

Tags: video-streaming, audio-streaming, voip, bandwidth-throttling

I'm looking into audio and video streaming (at the same time) between a provider and a consumer and I am wondering what are the best/common solutions to handle the balancing between audio and video when it comes to CPU and bandwidth.

This is for a proof of concept just to get the idea behind things so **I am not** looking into libraries that implement any of this, but instead I'm more interested in algorithms and design concepts/patterns to handle managing bandwidth and CPU for the two streams (audio and video).

Generally speaking, what is the common approach?
Any good primers out there?

Cheers

Comment: It's hard to answer this question when we aren't sure if you are talking about the encoding side or decoding side, and without at least a general idea of what you are trying to do and the quality you are trying to achieve.  It would also be helpful to know your latency requirements.

Comment: This is a "streaming" for dummies kind of thing. I'm not concerned (at this point) with encoding/decoding but more with how it works, the approaches taken, etc...

Comment: Can you at least give an example of what you are doing?  Again, it is not possible to answer your question at all without knowing what you are asking.  Encoding and decoding media have little to do with each other, and are completely independent issues.  Bandwidth management has much to do with whether or not high latency matters.  You need to give us at least something to go off of.  The difference between picking up your phone and calling someone is different than the process for communicating with the Mars Rover.

Comment: I see what you are saying. Well It can be something like skype or voip buster, etc... It has to have low latency because it's "live". But like I said, it's more a generic approach I'm looking for.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this will answer your question.
There is adaptive streaming technologies such as HLS and MPEG-DASH. 
Those will adapt based on bandwidth and CPU performance as well.